How to display variation images for every variation quantity attribute in WooCommerce dropdown single product page
I'm trying to display a variation image for every option in the product page template. I have a product with 1-pack, 2-pack and 3-pack quantity attributes and I want to show an image for every single attribute.
Is there a hook I can use to output the image inside the php loop or should I edit the template file?
This is the variable.php template file:
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

$attribute_keys  = array_keys( $attributes );
$variations_json = wp_json_encode( $available_variations );
$variations_attr = function_exists( 'wc_esc_json' ) ? wc_esc_json( $variations_json ) : _wp_specialchars( $variations_json, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo $variations_attr; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', __( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label></th>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
                                    array(
                                        'options'   => $options,
                                        'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                                        'product'   => $product,
                                    )
                                );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_table' ); ?>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            <?php
                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_single_variation. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
                 *
                 * @since 2.4.0
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' );


I tried editing the php template file, but I'm not sure how to get the variation image.

Each variation should have it's own unique post ID, so you'd just get the variation image the same way you'd get a featured image/thumbnail for a post.

This feature is part of woo. https://themes.woo.com/storefront/product/ship-your-idea-2/ just switch between colors..
